# PIL package not installing using bbfreezer

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, openpyxl

I am trying to package a Python 2.7 script into an exe so that it can be run in environments that do not have Python natively installed. The script executes fully when running in Python, but when I run it as an exe I get this error:

```
ImportError: You must install PIL to fetch image objects
```

PIL is needed for another package I run in my script, openpyxl. I am on the latest version of openpyxl (2.4.2).

Here is my bbfreeze import script:

```
   from bbfreeze import Freezer
   f = Freezer("AthenaHighDef", includes('csv','datetime','sqlite3','calendar','operator', 'os', 'dateutil', 'openpyxl', 'PIL', 'winsound'))
   f.addScript ("athenahighdef.py")
   f()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing PIL using bbfreeze, it also requires that 'pkg_resources', 'numbers', and 'pipes' be part of the "includes" clause when formulating the script.

```
f = Freezer("PilTest", includes=('PIL', 'pkg_resources', 'numbers', 'pipes'))
```